# Hide colorbox title text on hover, show as photo caption with full size image

Tags: colorbox

I'm using colorbox on a site but haven't been able to figure out how turn off the title text when hovering over a thumbnail. I want to retain the text to use as a photo caption when you see the full size image, just hide it on the thumbnail hover state.

I've seen some js solutions to completely turn them off, which isn't what I want. I also messed around the with the colorbox js itself and was able to turn off the text for the full size image but that is the reverse of what I want. My skills are HTML and CSS... I have experimented with qtip but that is a little beyond me right now.

My HTML is basically this:

```
 <li class="imgTitle"><a class="group1" href="images/bigPhoto.png" title="This tooltip is showing all the formatting tags like <br /> that I need to style my big photo caption <br />No one wants to see this HTML code while hovering over a thumbnail<br />Can I turn it off until you actually click the image<img src="images/thumbnailPhoto.png" /></a> </li>
```

Any help would be appreciated--thanks!

Comment: Anyone want to take a shot at this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using some (hidden) element other than the `title` attribute, then as a setting in your colorbox, set the `title` option to a displayed copy of that element, for example:

HTML:

```
<li class="imgTitle">
  <a class="group1" href="images/bigPhoto.png">
    <span class="caption" style="display: none;">
      I'm a caption that's not in a title attribute anymore
    </span>
    <img src="images/thumbnailPhoto.png" />
  </a>
</li>
```

JS could be something like this:

```
$(".group1").colorbox({
  title: function() {
    return $(this).find("span.caption").clone().show();
  },
  // other settings/options here
});
```

Here is **[a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbqrfq73/)** similar to the above.  I added the `.clone()` part because, when I was implementing something similar in a gallery, they disappeared after clicking once through all the images.

Comment: Thanks for the code, Max. I tried it out on my page and the caption is still hidden when active, but that's probably my own styles interfering. That fiddle does what I need so I will try to implement that into my page. Thanks again!